# Login once for different urls in shiny app

Tags: authentication, shiny

I have multiple shiny apps each of which have a unique url. ( I did this to increase loading speed)
Now I want to have authentication only in the first page and once user is logged in, they become logged in in all other urls.
How Can I do this?

at the moment all I found is how to setup a login page for a single shiny app. but once the user is redirected to another url which is another shiny app, another authentication is required.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If your apps are under the same domain, you can use cookies.